# ICEFaces + Liferay : how to set value for public-render-parameter

Tags: liferay, icefaces

ICEFaces + Liferay  : I created two war file firstApp.war and secondApp.war  file and deployed on liferay.
I want to implement, when I click submit button on firstApp.war application’s page , firstAppBacking bean should set some value in public-render-parameter so that I can get that value in  secondApp.war application something like IPC. Please sugeest me how can i set the valiue in firstAppText.

```
<portlet-app ....>
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>firstApp</portlet-name>
    <display-name>First App</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.portlet.MainPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>com.icesoft.faces.VIEW</name>
        <value>/jsp/firstApp.iface</value>
    </init-param>
    ....
    **<supported-public-render-parameter>firstAppText</supported-public-render-parameter>**
</portlet>
<public-render-parameter>
    <identifier>firstAppText</identifier>
    <qname xmlns:x="http://www.liferay.com/public-render-parameters">x:firstAppText</qname>
</public-render-parameter>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. First of all, the basic concepts are well described [here](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2008/03/liferay-session-sharing-demystified.html).

As you can see, you can share data in different "contexts". One way is to share the data via the session by declaring shared-portlet-session-attribute in portlet.xml, e.g.

```
<shared-portlet-session-attribute> 
   <name>someName</name>
   <java-class>com.some.class</java-class>
<shared-portlet-session-attribute>
```

Other ways to share data are:
- PortletSession
- PortletContext
- Page Parameters
- Portlet Events

The different ways are described in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194702). I haven't yet tried all of them, therefore I cannot give more details now.